# Variable "to" address in PHP Mailer

Tags: phpmailer, email, php

I am trying to set the "to" address for an email sent via an html form utilizing phpmailer. The end goal is to utilize a droplist to let the user select which person they are contacting depending on their needs. However, as I don't know much about PHP I'm going step by step and am already stuck.

I'm using the example that came with the site I purchased, but trying to modify it to include a to field. Right now I'm simply trying to get a new variable to show up but have not succeeded. This is the HTML form I have in place right now:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="phpmailer.php" class="af-form" id="af-form">
<div class="af-outer af-required">
    <div class="af-inner">
        <label for="toemail" id="toemail_label">To Whom:</label>
        <input type="text" name="toemail" id="toemail" size="30" value="" class="text-input span8"/>
        <label class="error" for="toemail" id="toemail_error">To field is required.</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="af-outer af-required">
    <div class="af-inner">
        <label for="name" id="name_label">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input span8"/>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">Name is required.</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="af-outer af-required">
    <div class="af-inner">
        <label for="email" id="email_label">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input span8"/>
        <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">Email is required.</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="af-outer af-required">
    <div class="af-inner">
        <label for="input-message" id="message_label">Your Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="input-message" cols="30" class="text-input span8"></textarea>
        <label class="error" for="input-message" id="message_error">Message is required.</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="af-outer af-required">
    <div class="af-inner">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-button btn btn-large" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message!" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The name, email, and message fields get picked up fine and populate in the email I recieve. However, the "toemail" field doesn't show up. Here is the process.php I am using for phpmailer.

```
    <?php
if ((isset($_POST['toemail'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['toemail'])) > 0)) {
    $toemail = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['toemail']));
} else {$toemail = 'No to address entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0)) {
    $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
} else {$name = 'No name entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) > 0)) {
    $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
} else {$email = 'No email entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['message'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['message'])) > 0)) {
    $message = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
} else {$message = 'No phone entered';}
ob_start();d
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>To Whom:</td>
    <td><?=$toemail;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?=$name;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?=$email;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Message</td>
    <td><?=$message;?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?
$body = ob_get_contents();

$to = 'personalemailtousefortesting.com';
$email = 'email@example.com';
$fromaddress = "you@example.com";
$fromname = "Online Contact";

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = "mail@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Contact Form";
$mail->AddAddress("mypersonalemailfortestingpurposes@gmail.com","Name 1"); // addresses here

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  "Contact form submitted";
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'mypersonalemailfortestingpurposes@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact form failed';
    $content = $body;   
  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: mail@yourdomain.com\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}
?>
```

The email I get populates the name, email, and message fields fine, however, I get my fall back error message of 'No to address entered' for the "toemail" input.

This is issue number one. I'll post the phpmailer.php that I'm using if anyone needs to see it. I do not know if I need to define the variable in there first.

After I get that working, I need to make it work for a dropdown list so the user cannot just send the email to whomever they would like.

THEN, I need to set that as the actual send-to address. I do not know how to set the actual address for sending purposes. I would assume that I change

```
    $mail->AddAddress("mypersonalemailfortestingpurposes@gmail.com","Name 1"); // addresses here
```

to something like...

```
    $mail->AddAddress($toemail,"Name 1"); // addresses here
```

...but odds are that's not correct.

Any help you can provide would be wonderful.

If you need to see my phpmailer.php I can post that too.

Thanks again,

-Rocky Colt TumTum

Comment: BUMP!! Still haven't gotten a response on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you didn't find this, this is what was listed on the PHP Manual site.

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure how that helps me.

Comment: I see that they are setting up multiple recipients, however, I am trying to set up "variable" recpients. So depending on what "To Whom:" person is selected in the contact form, will determine where the email goes. I hope that makes more sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *BUMP* I still haven't figured this out, I've been reading everything I can get my hands on and I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Anyone have ANY insight onto this. Is it possible? Is it something super easy I'm just missing? Hello?